# Swift constrain view to other view that has been transformed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `highlightView` which I would like to `constraint` to another `view`. This is my function for it:

```
func showHighlightView(viewToHighlight: UIView, height: CGFloat) {
    self.view.addSubview(highlightView)
    highlightView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToHighlight.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    highlightView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: highlightView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    
    highlightView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToHighlight.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    highlightView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewToHighlight.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    highlightView.layer.cornerRadius = height/2

    highlightView.layer.add(self.scaleAnimation, forKey: "scale")

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(viewToHighlight)
}
```

This is working for most of my cases. However I have one `view` which I `transform` like this:

```
var transformerBumbleBee = CGAffineTransform.identity
transformerBumbleBee = transformerBumbleBee.translatedBy(x: 25, y: -80)
transformerBumbleBee = transformerBumbleBee.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 1)
self.addListButton.transform = transformerBumbleBee
```

with this `addListButton` my `showHightLightView()` is constraining to the `identity-constraint` of `addListButton` and not the `transformed`. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` doesn't apply constraints to other views , you need to make translate and scale actions with changing the constraints's constants/multipliers values

Answer (score 0):

Transformations can not be used along with constraints, probably you may receive some runtime warnings related to constraints if you use the code above.

Use either of the way, just add view as subview programatically in view and apply transformations.